# IN operator in Couchbase Lite

Tags: couchbase-lite, sql++

I need to query something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM `sample` WHERE id IN ["123", "456"]
```

This is converted into `QueryBuilder` as below

```swift
QueryBuilder
   .select(SelectResult.all())
   .from(DataSource.database("sample"))
   .where(Expression.property("id")
          .in([
                Expression.string("123"), 
                Expression.string("456")
              ])
         )
```

This doesn't work, and return empty list of result, any idea?

Comment: Can you please say why you think this doesn't work?  Do you have any documents with id="123" or "456"

Comment: Uhm ... looks like it's my bad. The statement works as expected, I somehow managed to NOT saving the data successfully ... Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 1):

I see from your comments that your code worked (it was false negative). Yet I'll share an approach which may be useful in case you need to use the `like` operator against multiple wildcarded (`%`) expressions. Sample is in Kotlin language:

```kotlin
val list = listOf("123", "456")
val items = list.map { Meta.id.like(Expression.string("$it-%")) }.toMutableList()
val whereExpression = items
        .fold(items.removeAt(0)) { chain, next -> chain.or(next) }
val query = QueryBuilder.select(
        SelectResult.expression(Meta.id),
        SelectResult.all()
    ).from(DataSource.database(this.db)).where(whereExpression)
val results = query.execute()
val resultList = results.allResults()
```